# How to format a string for $_POST that contains HTML and URL with & using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am creating a drag and drop website builder. I have multiple HTML objects that can be dragged onto the page to create a website. Some objects contain URL's and some don't. When I click on a save button, a JavaScript function is triggered and the HTML code takes all the HTML content within the main div object and stores it in a 
JavaScript variable with a string value. The code example below is just a sample

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <iframe class="img-responsive" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=33.442341,-111.959608&amp;z=15&amp;output=embed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" data-url="">
            </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am using AJAX to POST the value to a php page to save the data to an sql database table. When I echo the $_POST value of the string I get the string below.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <iframe class="img-responsive" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=33.442341,-111.959608
```

It appears that the string is being cut off at &. How do I encode the string to fix this? I am trying to store the html code in sql server so I can retrieve the code and recreate the page for editing. What is the best way to encode the html in JavaScript.

Comment: I'd look at base64. atob/bota base64_encode/base64_decode

Comment: What do I use then in place of escape()?

Answer (score 0):

I used the JavaScript escape() function and it works perfectly now.

Comment: `escape()` is deprecated, not unicode safe, and should not be used.